# Upload HTML only file to appfog

Tags: html, web, upload, appfog

I'm new to Appfog and didn't see any documentation on how to upload files that were html only. I'm not sure what to select when it asks what code I am using: it lists things like python, flask, java, etc, as options but not html. Where do I put my html code and what is the default wsgi.py file supposed to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create an HTML only app use PHP as the runtime and **do not use standalone** even when the af tool detects standanlone:

```
af push                
Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]: y
Application Name: [APP NAME]
Detected a Standalone Application, is this correct? [Yn]: n #<< NOPE
1: Rails
2: Spring
3: Grails
4: Lift
5: JavaWeb
6: Standalone
7: Sinatra
8: Node
9: PHP
10: Erlang/OTP Rebar
11: WSGI
12: Django
13: Rack
14: Play
Select Application Type: 9 #<< PHP will do
Selected PHP Application
1: AWS US East - Virginia
2: AWS EU West - Ireland
3: AWS Asia SE - Singapore
4: Rackspace AZ 1 - Dallas
5: HP AZ 2 - Las Vegas
Select Infrastructure: 1
Application Deployed URL [your app name.aws.af.cm]: 
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [128M]: 
How many instances? [1]: 
Bind existing services to 'app name'? [yN]: n #<< dont need services
Create services to bind to 'app name'? [yN]: n #<< no bindings
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]: n
```

Make sure your root folder has an index.html